# Python + Pyside + QThreads emit signal and segmentation fault

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, signals-slots, qthread

Hello I'm new in python and PySide, and after hours of research I'm try to develop a simple GUI to show some data from API service.

I program is "simple", I implemented Qthread and have worker thread that make the request to api and emits signal to Main thread with QObject as argument.

The main thread receives the signal and update the GUI.

The problem is i have segmentation fault error when run the program.

Before implement the api request i try simple pass a number as string and works perfectly.

I think my error comes when my main thread try to access the GObject and my worker thread also try to access that object.

Heres my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import time
from termcolor import colored
from blessings import Terminal


class MySig(QtCore.QObject):
    sig = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QObject)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = 10
        self.signal = MySig()


    def callAping(self, jsonrpc_req):
        url = "https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1"
        headers = { 'X-Application' : '***********', 'X-Authentication' : '**************************' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(url, jsonrpc_req, headers)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            jsonResponse = response.read()
            return jsonResponse
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print 'Oops no service available at ' + str(url)
            exit()
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            print 'Oops not a valid operation from the service ' + str(url)
            exit()

    def getMarketBookBestOffers(self):

        marketId = "1.116260985"
        market_book_req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketBook", "params": {"marketIds":["' + marketId + '"],"priceProjection":{"priceData":["EX_BEST_OFFERS"]}}, "id": 1}'
        """
        print  market_book_req
        """
        market_book_response = self.callAping(market_book_req)
        """
        print market_book_response
        """
        market_book_loads = json.loads(market_book_response)
        try:
            market_book_result = market_book_loads['result']
            return market_book_result
        except:
            print  'Exception from API-NG' + str(market_book_result['error'])
            exit()


    def run(self):
        while True:
            market_book_result = self.getMarketBookBestOffers()
            self.signal.sig.emit(market_book_result)
            time.sleep(0.5)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.selid1 = QtGui.QLabel('id', self)
        self.price11 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)
        self.price12 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)

        self.hbox1=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.selid1)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.price11)
        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.price12)

        self.selid2 = QtGui.QLabel('id', self)
        self.price21 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)
        self.price22 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)

        self.hbox2=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.selid2)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.price21)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.price22)

        self.selid3 = QtGui.QLabel('id', self)
        self.price31 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)
        self.price32 = QtGui.QLabel('0.0', self)

        self.hbox3=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.selid3)
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.price31)
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.price32)

        self.vbox=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox1)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox3)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Absolute')

        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.signal.sig.connect(self.changelabel)

    def changelabel(self, datas):       
        if(datas is not None):
            for marketBook in datas:
                runners = marketBook['runners']
                if (runners[0]['status'] == 'ACTIVE'):
                    self.selid1.setText(runners[0]['status'])
                    self.price11.setText(str(runners[0]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']))
                    self.price12.setText(str(runners[0]['ex']['availableToLay'][0]['price']))
                else:
                    self.selid1.setText(runners[0]['status'])

                if (runners[1]['status'] == 'ACTIVE'):
                    self.selid2.setText(runners[1]['status'])
                    self.price21.setText(str(runners[1]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']))
                    self.price22.setText(str(runners[1]['ex']['availableToLay'][0]['price']))
                else:
                    self.selid2.setText(runners[1]['status'])

                if (runners[2]['status'] == 'ACTIVE'):
                    self.selid3.setText(runners[2]['status'])
                    self.price31.setText(str(runners[2]['ex']['availableToBack'][0]['price']))
                    self.price32.setText(str(runners[2]['ex']['availableToLay'][0]['price']))
                else:
                    self.selid3.setText(runners[2]['status'])


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `MySig` class, and the signal should not be defined to emit a `QObject` because that does not match the type of object you are emitting.

I cannot test your example code, but try this:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    sig = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = 10
    ...

    def run(self):
        ...
        self.sig.emit(market_book_result)
    ...

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    ...
    def initUI(self):    
        ...
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.sig.connect(self.changelabel)
        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: Hello thanks thats resolve my problem.

but where is the problem? is when i try to declare my signal?

And if i start the thread before connect the signal it is wrong? will i lose some emit signal?

Thanks again

Comment: @asa. I think the problem is the declaration of the signal (i.e. using `QObject` instead of `object`). But you can easily test each possibility to make sure.